# Puppeteer loop table rows - select dropdown option on each row "Option "P" for parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm try to use Puppeteer to loop through a  table elements rows.  Each row, within the last column of the table, has a dropdown. I want to select option "P" for Parameters and get all the href links and create an array of those....then enter one by one to take a screenshot.

Here is my table element...

I hope someone could help me with the steps of the loop and clicking on the dropdown to select an option - building the array of links then clicking into each link and taking the snapshot.

Thanks for your help

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="96%" style="border: 2px solid black; margin-bottom: 10px;">



<tbody><tr class="header1">
  <th colspan="8">Workshops</th>
</tr>
<tr class="header2"><th><acronym style="cursor:help;" title="Franchise Code">FC</acronym></th><th><acronym style="cursor:help;" title="Status">S</acronym></th><th>Date</th><th><acronym style="cursor:help;" title="Category">Cat.</acronym></th><th>Name</th><th>Location</th><th>Disc.</th><!--<th>Created</th>--><th></th></tr>
<tr style="background-color: white;">
        <td valign="top" style="font-size: 9px;">EC</td>
    <td valign="top" style="font-size: 9px;">
    <acronym style="cursor: help;" title="  Expired">E
    
    </acronym></td>
        
    <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-size: 9px;">04.04.20</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-size: 8px;">CS</td>
    <td valign="top" style="font-size: 9px;">Intermediate Workshop Derby</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-size: 9px;">Spondon Village Hall, Sitwell Street, Spondon, Derby, DE21 7FG</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-size: 9px;">None</td>
<!--    <td valign="top" align="center" style="font-size: 9px;">26.09.19 12.11</td> -->

    <td valign="top" align="right" style="font-size: 9px;" nowrap="nowrap">
        <form action="" method="get">
        <select name="x" size="1" onchange="location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 40px;">
        
        <option value="#" title="Select an action"> -- </option>
        
        
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Parameters/14460?CLEAR" title="Parameters">P</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Parameters/14460?CLEAR" title="Parameters">P</a> -->
                
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Teachers/14460?CLEAR" title="Teachers">T</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Teachers/14460?CLEAR" title="Teachers">T</a> -->
                
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Franchise/14460?CLEAR" title="Franchise">F</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Franchise/14460?CLEAR" title="Franchise">F</a> -->
                
                
        <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshop_Profiles?workshopRef=IntDerby04Apr20" title="User Profiles">U</option>
        <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshop_Waitlist?workshopRef=IntDerby04Apr20" title="Wait List">W</option>
    <!--    <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshop_Profiles?workshopRef=IntDerby04Apr20" title="User Profiles">U</a>
        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshop_Waitlist?workshopRef=IntDerby04Apr20" title="Wait List">W</a>-->
        
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Edit/14460?CLEAR" title="Edit">E</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Edit/14460?CLEAR" title="Edit">E</a> -->
                
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Copy/14460?CLEAR" title="Copy">C</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Copy/14460?CLEAR" title="Copy">C</a> -->
                
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Abort/14460?CLEAR" title="Abort">A</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Abort/14460?CLEAR" title="Abort">A</a> -->
                
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Delete/14460?CLEAR" title="Delete">D</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Delete/14460?CLEAR" title="Delete">D</a> -->
                
                        
        
        </select>
        </form>
    </td></tr>
<tr style="background-color: #eeeeee;">
        <td valign="top" style="font-size: 9px;">JK</td>
    <td valign="top" style="font-size: 9px;">
    <acronym style="cursor: help;" title="  Aborted">A
    
    </acronym></td>
        
    <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-size: 9px;">04.04.20</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-size: 8px;">Workshop</td>
    <td valign="top" style="font-size: 9px;">Intermediate Building Blocks 2 (10:30am-1:30pm)</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-size: 9px;">Colwick Community Centre, Vale Road, Colwick, Nottingham, NG4 2GP</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-size: 9px;">None</td>
<!--    <td valign="top" align="center" style="font-size: 9px;">05.03.20 13.18</td> -->

    <td valign="top" align="right" style="font-size: 9px;" nowrap="nowrap">
        <form action="" method="get">
        <select name="x" size="1" onchange="location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 40px;">
        
        <option value="#" title="Select an action"> -- </option>
        
        
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Parameters/14560?CLEAR" title="Parameters">P</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Parameters/14560?CLEAR" title="Parameters">P</a> -->
                
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Teachers/14560?CLEAR" title="Teachers">T</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Teachers/14560?CLEAR" title="Teachers">T</a> -->
                
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Franchise/14560?CLEAR" title="Franchise">F</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Franchise/14560?CLEAR" title="Franchise">F</a> -->
                
                
        <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshop_Profiles?workshopRef=IBB2Apr20" title="User Profiles">U</option>
        <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshop_Waitlist?workshopRef=IBB2Apr20" title="Wait List">W</option>
    <!--    <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshop_Profiles?workshopRef=IBB2Apr20" title="User Profiles">U</a>
        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshop_Waitlist?workshopRef=IBB2Apr20" title="Wait List">W</a>-->
        
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Edit/14560?CLEAR" title="Edit">E</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Edit/14560?CLEAR" title="Edit">E</a> -->
                
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Copy/14560?CLEAR" title="Copy">C</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Copy/14560?CLEAR" title="Copy">C</a> -->
                
                
                        
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Delete/14560?CLEAR" title="Delete">D</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Delete/14560?CLEAR" title="Delete">D</a> -->
                
                        
        
        </select>
        </form>
    </td></tr>
<tr style="background-color: white;">
        <td valign="top" style="font-size: 9px;">JK</td>
    <td valign="top" style="font-size: 9px;">
    <acronym style="cursor: help;" title="  Aborted">A
    
    </acronym></td>
        
    <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-size: 9px;">04.04.20</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-size: 8px;">Workshop</td>
    <td valign="top" style="font-size: 9px;">Beginner Improver (2:30pm-5:30pm)</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-size: 9px;">Colwick Community Centre, Vale Road, Colwick, Nottingham, NG4 2GP</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-size: 9px;">None</td>
<!--    <td valign="top" align="center" style="font-size: 9px;">05.03.20 13.19</td> -->

    <td valign="top" align="right" style="font-size: 9px;" nowrap="nowrap">
        <form action="" method="get">
        <select name="x" size="1" onchange="location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 40px;">
        
        <option value="#" title="Select an action"> -- </option>
        
        
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Parameters/14561?CLEAR" title="Parameters">P</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Parameters/14561?CLEAR" title="Parameters">P</a> -->
                
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Teachers/14561?CLEAR" title="Teachers">T</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Teachers/14561?CLEAR" title="Teachers">T</a> -->
                
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Franchise/14561?CLEAR" title="Franchise">F</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Franchise/14561?CLEAR" title="Franchise">F</a> -->
                
                
        <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshop_Profiles?workshopRef=BegImpApr20" title="User Profiles">U</option>
        <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshop_Waitlist?workshopRef=BegImpApr20" title="Wait List">W</option>
    <!--    <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshop_Profiles?workshopRef=BegImpApr20" title="User Profiles">U</a>
        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshop_Waitlist?workshopRef=BegImpApr20" title="Wait List">W</a>-->
        
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Edit/14561?CLEAR" title="Edit">E</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Edit/14561?CLEAR" title="Edit">E</a> -->
                
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Copy/14561?CLEAR" title="Copy">C</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Copy/14561?CLEAR" title="Copy">C</a> -->
                
                
                        
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Delete/14561?CLEAR" title="Delete">D</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Delete/14561?CLEAR" title="Delete">D</a> -->
                
                        
        
        </select>
        </form>
    </td></tr>
<tr style="background-color: #eeeeee;">
        <td valign="top" style="font-size: 9px;">MJ</td>
    <td valign="top" style="font-size: 9px;">
    <acronym style="cursor: help;" title="  Expired">E
    
    </acronym></td>
        
    <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-size: 9px;">04.04.20</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-size: 8px;">Intermediate</td>
    <td valign="top" style="font-size: 9px;">Jango Workshop - add beautiful tango moves &amp; techniques to your dancing. 1700-1930</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-size: 9px;">SHIFNAL VILLAGE HALL, ASTON STREET, SHIFNAL, TF11 8DW</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-size: 9px;">None</td>
<!--    <td valign="top" align="center" style="font-size: 9px;">04.02.20 00.25</td> -->

    <td valign="top" align="right" style="font-size: 9px;" nowrap="nowrap">
        <form action="" method="get">
        <select name="x" size="1" onchange="location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 40px;">
        
        <option value="#" title="Select an action"> -- </option>
        
        
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Parameters/14554?CLEAR" title="Parameters">P</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Parameters/14554?CLEAR" title="Parameters">P</a> -->
                
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Teachers/14554?CLEAR" title="Teachers">T</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Teachers/14554?CLEAR" title="Teachers">T</a> -->
                
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Franchise/14554?CLEAR" title="Franchise">F</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Franchise/14554?CLEAR" title="Franchise">F</a> -->
                
                
        <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshop_Profiles?workshopRef=Shif-APR20" title="User Profiles">U</option>
        <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshop_Waitlist?workshopRef=Shif-APR20" title="Wait List">W</option>
    <!--    <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshop_Profiles?workshopRef=Shif-APR20" title="User Profiles">U</a>
        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshop_Waitlist?workshopRef=Shif-APR20" title="Wait List">W</a>-->
        
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Edit/14554?CLEAR" title="Edit">E</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Edit/14554?CLEAR" title="Edit">E</a> -->
                
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Copy/14554?CLEAR" title="Copy">C</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Copy/14554?CLEAR" title="Copy">C</a> -->
                
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Abort/14554?CLEAR" title="Abort">A</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Abort/14554?CLEAR" title="Abort">A</a> -->
                
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Delete/14554?CLEAR" title="Delete">D</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Delete/14554?CLEAR" title="Delete">D</a> -->
                
                        
        
        </select>
        </form>
    </td></tr>
<tr style="background-color: white;">
        <td valign="top" style="font-size: 9px;">LT</td>
    <td valign="top" style="font-size: 9px;">
    <acronym style="cursor: help;" title="  Current">C
    
    </acronym></td>
        
    <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-size: 9px;">24.02.22</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-size: 8px;">Workshop</td>
    <td valign="top" style="font-size: 9px;">SILC Academy</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-size: 9px;">Copford Village Hall, 80 School Road, Copford, Colchester, Essex, CO6 1BX</td>
    <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-size: 9px;">None</td>
<!--    <td valign="top" align="center" style="font-size: 9px;">08.01.19 18.49</td> -->

    <td valign="top" align="right" style="font-size: 9px;" nowrap="nowrap">
        <form action="" method="get">
        <select name="x" size="1" onchange="location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 40px;">
        
        <option value="#" title="Select an action"> -- </option>
        
        
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Parameters/14280?CLEAR" title="Parameters">P</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Parameters/14280?CLEAR" title="Parameters">P</a> -->
                
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Teachers/14280?CLEAR" title="Teachers">T</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Teachers/14280?CLEAR" title="Teachers">T</a> -->
                
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Franchise/14280?CLEAR" title="Franchise">F</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Franchise/14280?CLEAR" title="Franchise">F</a> -->
                
                
        <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshop_Profiles?workshopRef=SA 24/2/19" title="User Profiles">U</option>
        <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshop_Waitlist?workshopRef=SA 24/2/19" title="Wait List">W</option>
    <!--    <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshop_Profiles?workshopRef=SA 24/2/19" title="User Profiles">U</a>
        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshop_Waitlist?workshopRef=SA 24/2/19" title="Wait List">W</a>-->
        
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Edit/14280?CLEAR" title="Edit">E</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Edit/14280?CLEAR" title="Edit">E</a> -->
                
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Copy/14280?CLEAR" title="Copy">C</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Copy/14280?CLEAR" title="Copy">C</a> -->
                
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Abort/14280?CLEAR" title="Abort">A</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Abort/14280?CLEAR" title="Abort">A</a> -->
                
                
                <option value="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Delete/14280?CLEAR" title="Delete">D</option>
<!--        <a href="/Applications/COS/Administration/Workshops/Delete/14280?CLEAR" title="Delete">D</a> -->
                
                        
        
        </select>
        </form>
    </td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my own solution to the problem for anyone else who comes here.

The code below is looking for all the select tags where the name starts with "x".

It then gets the length of the object - loops through all the elements to extract option 1 value from each!  That what was what I needed.

```
       var sel;
       const relevantValues = [];
       for(var z=0; z<selects.length; z++){
       sel = selects[z];
       if(sel.name.indexOf('x') === 0){
       relevantValues.push(sel.options[1].value);
     };
     };
```